# Spring Cloud Contract generates weak tests using bodyFromFile in contract file

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-cloud-contract

I try to implement simple contract for `get users` REST Endpoit. I expect that Spring Cloud Contract generates test whitch checks json response more strongly. Can anyone know how to configure test generator?
My contract `yaml` file here:

```
  Get Users contract
request:
  method: GET
  url: /users
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
response:
  status: 200
  bodyFromFile: get_users_response.json
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
```

and `get_users_response.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "User2"
  }
]
```

Spring Cloud Contract generates:

```
...
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().contains("['id']").isEqualTo(1);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().contains("['name']").isEqualTo("User1");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().contains("['id']").isEqualTo(2);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().contains("['name']").isEqualTo("User2");
...
```

But I assumed something like this:

```
//check the correspondent element
assertThatJson(parsedJson).elementWithIndex(0).field("['id']").isEqualTo(1);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).elementWithIndex(0).field("['name']").isEqualTo("");
assertThatJson(parsedJson).elementWithIndex(1).field("['id']").isEqualTo(2);
assertThatJson(parsedJson).elementWithIndex(1).field("[name']").isEqualTo(1);
//and check array size
assertThatJson(parsedJson).array().hasSize(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on the array size check. Check the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-limitations . For your convenience I'm copying the part of the docs

> The support for verifying the size of JSON arrays is experimental. If you want to turn it on, set the value of the following system property to true: spring.cloud.contract.verifier.assert.size. By default, this feature is set to false. You can also set the assertJsonSize property in the plugin configuration.

Comment: Thank's. spring.cloud.contract.verifier.assert.size works for check size but we have a problem with "cross values" when ckeck an arrays. The test in my example will pass also for {id:1, name:User2} and {id:2, name:User1}

Comment: That's an experimental feature so if you have any feedback about things not working you can file an issue